# worldwide popular or popular worldwide

Tags: adjectives, word-order, modifiers

> 1.Thai boxing has become increasingly **worldwide popular** in recent years.
>
> 2.Thai boxing has become increasingly **popular worldwide** in recent years.

Which position is better for "worldwide", "popular worldwide" or "worldwide popular"?

Comment: Certainly _increasingly locally popular_ sounds less idiomatic than _increasingly popular locally,_ and spatial adverbs like _worldwide_ seem to prefer to follow an adjective complement as in no. 2, but I can't find a reference to support that notion.

Comment: Your alternative #1 sentence might be "Thai boxing has increasing worldwide popularity in recent years."

Answer (score 1):

*[Worldwide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/worldwide)* is not an adjective in your sentence, it is an adverb.

As an adverb  it tells *to what  geographical extent*  'Thai boxing has become increasingly popular'. It is not just *locally* but *worldwide*.

See the other uses of *worldwide* as an adverb, and as an adjective in the link above to the Oxford Dictionary.

See this usage in a Cornell University blog as an authentic example:

> Thai Boxing is also known throughout the world for its ferocity, athleticism and potentially devastating maneuvers.  Muay Thai is Thailand’s national form of martial art that **has become increasingly popular worldwide** as seen in West in Mixed Martial Arts (MMA).

Note: customary usage is *as seen in the West*, so I think the blogger has made a typo or another error.

Answer (score 0):

Your title is misleading, given your quote.

As a two-word phrase, and with the verb *has become*, *popular worldwide* sounds more idiomatic than *worldwide popular:*

> *Boxing has become popular worldwide*.
>   <strike>Boxing has become worldwide popular</strike>.

However, your quote uses a three-word phrase, not a two-word phrase. The phrase *increasingly popular worldwide* sounds much more idiomatic than *increasingly worldwide popular*. The word “increasingly” changes the structure of the sentence enough to dictate and change in word order:

> *Boxing has become increasingly popular worldwide*.
>   <strike>Boxing has become increasingly worldwide popular</strike>.

[Here is a relevant Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=popular+worldwide%2Cworldwide+popular%2C+increasingly+popular+worldwide%2C+increasingly+worldwide+popular&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

When talking about something that has “become increasingly popular”, the word “increasingly” can be inserted between the verb “become” and the adjective “popular”, but the word “worldwide” belongs on the outside of the phrase. It could be moved to the beginning of the sentence:

> Worldwide, boxing has become increasingly popular.